# How do I access ng-repeat's scope from another directive on the same element that ng-repeat is on?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I want to be able to access a property from the `ng-repeat` scope in another directive of the same element where the `ng-repeat` directive resides. For example, I'd like to have access to the `child.class` property in the following example:

```
<div ng-class="{{ child.class }}" ng-repeat="child in parent.children">
    {{ child.name }}
</div>
```

[Here is a JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ywn5mrq3/) showing that this doesn't work.

If this isn't possible, what is the next best way to go about setting `class` on the element that has the `ng-repeat`? Is there a way to `ng-repeat` in a controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ng-class` takes an expression and evaluates it. If you change it to:

```
ng-class="child.class"
```

then it works! Here is a [working JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ywn5mrq3/1/).

Also just to mention, you can put in something like this:

```
ng-class="{'blue': true, 'red': false}"
```

`true` or `false` can be other variables or functions, but it only adds the classes with a value of `true`!

[ng-class documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass)

Comment: Haha I've gotta read documentation more closely. Thank you. I'll accept in 7 mins.